# ObjectAL clipping popping with iOS 9

Tags: ios9, objectal

My drum app was working fine until iOS 9 update. When playing sounds rapidly there is now a clipping popping type noise. All was well until IOS 9.
Not sure how to fix? 
Using OBjectAL which I love hopefully there is a fix.
Thanks!
Link to app
Handpan (by Jacob Cole) by Jacob Cole
https://appsto.re/us/CUbj8.i

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've found is that it's the samples that are buffered that make this popping sound. Thanks for any help

```
- (void)playD1 {
 //   [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playEffect:@"D1a.caf" ];

    int randomSoundNumber = arc4random() % 3; //random number from 0 to 2
    ALBuffer *buffer = self.D1Buffers[randomSoundNumber];
    NSLog(@"random sound number = %i", randomSoundNumber);
    self.D1Sources = [ALSource source];
    [self.D1Sources stop];
    [self.D1Sources play:buffer];
```